# How to convert a hex number that is a string type to a hex type

Tags: python

in python3

I have `a = '0e'`
The type of `a` is a `str`.
I want the type of `a` to be a hex

How do I do this?

`hex('0e')` gives and error
`'0e'.encode` gives `'3065'`, also not what I want.

I want `b = 0e` 
where `b` is type hex

Comment: I don't think that there is an hex type in Python