# how to XOR some string values as Hex values

Tags: python

I have a collection of values as strings and a collection of potential keys. I am trying to make 256 potential ascii strings given all potential one character strings.

```
my_text = '253224233b32242479'
print(my_text)
for key in string.printable: #all one character ascii charecter
    key = key.encode("hex")
    key = int(key, 16)
    key = key + 0x200
    key = hex(key)
    total_string = ""
    for x in range(0, len(my_text)/2): #scroll through all pairs of hex numbers
        original_letter = my_text[x*2:x*2+2]
        original_letter = int(original_letter, 16)
        original_letter = original_letter + 0x200
        original_letter_as_hex = hex(original_letter)
        xor_letter = original_letter_as_hex ^ key
        total_string = total_string.append(str(xor_letter))
    print(total_string)
print(total_string.decode("hex"))
```

My issue is that the `xor_letter = original_letter_as_hex ^ key` gives: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'`

So, how can I convert for instance '25' to something that can be 'XOR'ed as a hex?

This question is a more in depth question that I asked here: [How to convert a hex number that is a string type to a hex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104136/how-to-convert-a-hex-number-that-is-a-string-type-to-a-hex-type)

In short:

```
>>> key = '0'
>>> key = key.encode('hex')
>>> key = int(key, 16)
>>> key = key + 0x200
>>> key = hex(key)
>>> letter = '0e'
>>> letter = int(letter, 16)
>>> letter = letter + 0x200
>>> letter = hex(letter)
>>> done = key^letter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'
```

How do i do this? `done` should be '3e' which should convert to '>' in ascii.

One hex input `'0e'` XORed by one ascii input `'0'` is one ascii output `'>'`

I want a function that can take 2 inputs of as tpye strings and treat one as hex and one as ascii and XOR them like this site: http://xor.pw/?

Comment: What is type "hex?" Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Um, maybe there isn't one. I want a type that can be XORed somehow, any solution that does that will work.

Comment: You _had_ a type that could be XORed -- integers.  Then you used `hex` to turn your perfectly XORable number into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be very confused. There is no "hex type", there are `int`s. You still have not answered the crucial question of which version you are on. In any event, in Python 3:

```
>>> keys = bytes(string.printable, 'ascii')
>>> keys
b'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
>>> keys[0]
48
>>> key = keys[0]
>>> letter = '0e'
>>> letter = int(letter, 16)
>>> key += 0x200
>>> letter += 0x200
>>> done = key^letter
>>> done
62
```

Now, we can put this into another bytes object:

```
>>> bytes([done])
b'>'
```

Note the `b` prefix. Or, we can get a Python 3 `str`:

```
>>> bytes([done]).decode('ascii')
'>'
```

Or by simply using `chr`:

```
>>> chr(done)
'>'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is on Python 2 (otherwise `.encode("hex")` wouldn't have worked..)

Comment: @DSM maybe, I do think `.encode('hex')` existed on early versions of Python 3. I cannot recall.

Comment: Well, it's not in 3.1, which is the oldest I have at hand.  Then how about this: if he's using 3, `range(0, len(my_text)/2)` would have failed too. :-)

Comment: Honestly, I run it using python3, python2, sudo python3, and sudo python2 till it works.